# What type of probing sends GET /" data " to a server?

Tags: exploit, webserver

During monitoring of webserver logs I've stumbled upon those standard probings for wordpress exploits etc, like

```
No route found for "GET /wp-login.php" (uncaught exception)
No route found for "GET /administrator/" (uncaught exception)
No route found for "GET /admin.php"
```

which I understand. However sometimes I get GET requests like that one:

```
No route found for "GET /"   data   ""
```

that irritates me. What kind of probe is this? 
This is not a general approach of probing a webserver's response for a 404 page, isn't it?
Actually while writing this post I realized it could be a known exploit of some software.

Has somebody more information on this request?

Answer (score 1):

A `GET /` may return a default page or a directory listing which can give a lot of extra information to the caller. A default page, in particular, can be used to work out the exact software versions (OS, HTTP server...), which helps in knowing what known vulnerabilities may apply. A directory listing may, in turn, reveal some juicy sub-directories.

Comment: I disagree, this is not a simple GET / request but a "GET /"   data   " with the "   data   " data added.

Answer (score 0):

Did you find other obvious evidence from a tool automatically trying escape sequences/combining payloads?

This looks a bit like $automatic_scan_tool tried to combine payloads/text escapings/...

Comment: Some of them, like "GET /                                                    Result: �Ҳ���Post���ͱ��;" etc but mostly only the whitespace-data-whitespace part above

Comment: Is it some sort of API back-end, and is there a possibility of badly wirtten clients?

Comment: This is a symfony web framework log view. I doubt that this is legitimate data from the site passing through as all requests which work are well-formed. And the first three routes posted in my thread do definitely not exist.